# Argument unused during compilation: '-fembed-bitcode-marker'

Tags: static-libraries, xcode7, bitcode

I'm trying to build my library using bitcode! And I'm having strange issues. I added OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" in my xcconfig which works fine... unless I compile for a real phone as my target.

I'm using an iPhone 4s as a phone, and it tells me Argument unused during compilation: '-fembed-bitcode-marker'
If I try on any simulator (iPhone 4s simulator included) it works perfectly fine and I can see the bitcode using otool -l lib.a | grep LLVM

Anyone knows what could be the issues there?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you just enable bitcode in the *Build Settings* directly, without using `OTHER_CFLAGS`?

Comment: I wanted to test my application using a build with bitcode, so I could not build with archive to test as test build the library itself.

Comment: don't know what changed exactly, but now I just removed the other_cflags and I get "Clang error: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) canno't be used together. " (Still only on the phone)